# Accessors without the (), or const references to a member variable

Tags: c++, reference, accessor

I am interested in creating a class I can use like

```
class MyClass {
  vector<int> m_vec;
public:
  // Either this
  const& vector<int> vec;
  // Or some version of this. 
  const& vector<int> getVec() { return m_vec } ;

  MyClass() : vec(m_vec) {}
  void changeVec() { m_vec.push_back(5); }
}
```

Now if I want to use getVec(), the syntax is a little cumbersome:

```
myClass.getVec()[5]
```

I would much prefer to be able to either somehow use

```
myClass.vec[5]
```

without exposing the ability to modify the vector.  IE, I want the member variable to be private, but for a const-version of the variable to be public without a syntactical or performance overhead.

If I add the const& vector reference, the compiler (at least my version of GCC) actually makes the class take more memory.  So

1. How can I create an alias to a member variable without making it use more memory, or
2. How do I avoid the parens in the myVec()[] accessor?  Just defining myVec(int idx) is not a satisfactory option since I want to call multiple methods on it.

Just to be clear, this is an example -- in the real case, the usage is a bit more compelling than in the vector case.  Also, the memory usage *is* important as lots of these objects exist and will be copied, so this is not premature optimization.  At this point, I'm using the getVec()[0] approach, but the ugliness is killing me.

Comment: You could just make MyClass::operator[]

Comment: Unfortunately, the real case actually contains two of these vectors, ie myClass.boys()[0] and myClass.girls()[0].  Also, I want to be able to use other const functions of vector as well.  Basically, MyClass is mostly a dispatcher between the two different vectors.

Comment: There are infinite numbers of workarounds. *Why* can you not use the const reference you show here, as it seems to be the most appropriate?

Comment: Why not add some access functions boy and girl, so you can write MyClass.boy(0) to get the first boy?

Answer (score 5):

If, for some reason, `MyClass::operator[]` is not suitable, just make a tiny wrapper class for your vector.

```
struct Wrapper {
  friend class MyClass;
  int operator[](size_t s) const { return vec[s]; }
private:
  vector<int> vec;
};

class MyClass {
public:
  Wrapper vec;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're trying to solve the right problem here? One big purpose of classes is to avoid exposing the underlying implementation to users, and you're doing just such an exposition in this case.

You should really look carefully at your class's user API.

What operations really need to be done on the containers? You should design your API in such a way where the methods describe the high-level processes of the class, NOT in terms of "get me the hidden implementation details".

If you just need to provide access to the elements of the various containers you could provide begin/end iterators and allow algorithms that operate on ranges. Alternately you could provide functions like `for_each_boys` and `for_each_girls` that calls back the operand to the respective function.

Answer (score 3):

As a suggestion, you could overload `operator[]` for `MyClass`:

```
int operator[] (size_t which) const {
   return m_vec[which]; 
}
```

This simplifies the syntax to access the vector greatly: `myClass[5]`.  However, it becomes impractical if you a) want to expose more than one vector with your class or b) intend to use other `std::vector` members than just array subscripting, i.e. `size()` ... in that case you can't really avoid the getter and thus the parentheses.

Comment: @bsdfish: make it a function with two arguments, and use `()` instead of `[]`... and create general getters for the vectors themselves (ie not the elements, so that you can use the vector member functions.

Comment: You could index them like this: `myClassInstance[0][5]` (i.e. overload [] to return either the first or the second vector).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is:

```
struct MyClass
{
    vector<int> const vec;

    MyClass()
    {
        vector<int>& mvec = const_cast<vector<int>&>(vec);
        // modify mvec
    }
};
```

Comment: That will lead to UB since `vec` is declared `const`.

Comment: In practice the UB does not manifest itself. `std::vector<>` is always initialized by its constructors, so its members are always modifiable. The layout of const and non-const objects is the same...

Answer (score 1):

First things first: I don't see any point in doing this at all. Now if you intend on avoiding the `()[]` syntax --which I insist: I wouldn't-- you can just offer a reference to the type.

```
class test {
   std::vector<int> m_data;
public:
   std::vector<int> &data;
   test() : m_data(), data( m_data ) {}
};
```

The advantage over wrappers is that it is simpler to code, and there is not that much that can go wrong with it. The disadvantage is that you are leaking details of your implementation out: external code will depend on your object being implemented in terms of an `std::vector` for which you offer the reference. Note that there is not that much of a difference to this respect with the wrapper, as in both cases you are offering access to details (*I will offer you an indexed access into my internals*) which might or not be a good idea.

Other simple to code, not really nice solutions could imply using inheritance, as in:

```
class test : private std::vector<int>
{
public:
   using std::vector<int>::operator[];
};
```

An important detail here is that you *should not ever* inherit publicly from an STL container (as a matter of fact, being a `class`, the `private` keyword above is optional, as inheritance is by default private, but I have added it for emphasis), they were not designed to work polymorphicaly. By using private inheritance you are limiting the risk of user errors, as the vector is an implementation detail.

If at a later time you decide to change the vector for another container (that allows for indexed access -- again, you are promising indexed access in the interface!) you only need to provide your own `operator[]` implementations and user code will compile without changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this: (Not that I think it would be a particularly good idea...)

```
class MyClass;

class Proxy{
    public:
    Proxy(MyClass& c); // store reference to c
    int const& operator[](...) const; // access c.vec

    private:
    MyClass& c;
};

class MyClass{
    public:
    // public read-only proxy for this->m_vec
    const Proxy vec;

    MyClass()
        : vec(*this){
    }
    ...
    private:
    vector<int> m_vec;
};
```

Untested, but I'm sure you get the idea. This sort of pattern is useful for providing things like array slices.

Comment: That would increase the size of MyClass, which he wants to avoid.

Comment: Oh, didn't read that far... I guess this isn't suitable then.